# How to compute $\sum_{k=1}^n{k(k+1)(k+2)…(k+m)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to compute the sum:
$\sum_{k=1}^n{k(k+1)(k+2)…(k+m)}$
I know:
$\sum_{k=1}^n{k^2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$
and
$\sum_{k=1}^n{k^3}=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$
But calculate the above two formula method in here can not be used

Comment: Thanks,but I re-confirmed again, that is m

Comment: The sum at hand is a telescoping sum. $$\begin{align}k(k+1)\cdots(k+m) &= \frac{\color{red}{(k+m+1)}-\color{blue}{(k-1)}}{m+2}k(k+1)\cdots(k+m)\\ 
&= \frac{1}{m+2}\left(k(k+1)\cdots\color{red}{(k+m+1)} - \color{blue}{(k-1)}k\cdots(k+m)\right)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n{k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+m)}=(m+1)!\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{k+m}{m+1}$$
we know
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{k+m}{m+1}=\binom{n+m+1}{m+2}$$

Comment: What is C here? A constant?

Comment: $$C\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$

Comment: Ok. I've seen $C(n,r)$, $nCr$ and ${n \choose r}$, but never the combination $C{n \choose r}$. Just felt a bit confusing but Im sorry, just felt unusual.

Comment: @Christopher.L : it is not only you, now I am wondering if id ever seen that notation before as well.

Comment: $$(m-1)!\binom{k+m}{m-1}=\frac{(k+m)!}{(k+m-m+1)!}=(k+2)(k+3)\cdots(k+m)$$

Comment: @msm It was edited. Thanks.